# matlab2tikz not compiling

Tags: matlab2tikz

In the code generated by matlab2tikz, I am having a problem compiling the code. The error that I get is:

`! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
                }`

I am not seeing in the code where the error is. The brackets look correct.

Can you please help me get this matlab2tikz code to complie?  Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  %% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
  \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
  \usepackage{grffile}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%

  %% you may also want the following commands
  \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
  %\newlength\figureheight
  %\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
%\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.396in,
height=1.713in,
at={(0.883in,2.125in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
xmode=log,
xmin=0.1,
xmax=10000,
xtick={0.1,1,10,100,1000,10000},
xticklabels={\empty},
xminorticks=true,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
ymin=-150,
ymax=100,
ylabel={Magnitude (dB)},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-20   460\\
2e-16   373.97940008672\\
2e-11   273.97940008672\\
2e-07   193.97940008672\\
0.0002  133.97940008498\\
0.02    93.979382687181\\
0.2 73.9776604766519\\
0.233656357180521   72.6260737790347\\
0.272976466254357   71.2742556835082\\
0.318913433505023   69.9221218856437\\
0.372580755643581   68.5695574305924\\
0.435279310596225   67.2164056246064\\
0.508528890349814   65.8624529824047\\
0.594105040200952   64.5074088339076\\
0.694082097379708   63.1508777710172\\
0.810883472289793   61.7923225604558\\
0.947340391165627   60.4310144820835\\
1.10676052404865    59.0659673052162\\
1.29300816160207    57.6958503856501\\
1.51059788422311    56.3188758755282\\
1.76480399396087    54.9326552283403\\
2.06178836183266    53.5340218481269\\
2.40874978951507    52.1188211803692\\
2.8140985058872 50.6816786673865\\
3.28766002816376    49.215772040014\\
3.84091332914377    47.7126589387631\\
4.48726908366921    46.1622421642727\\
5.24239473889462    44.552983725662\\
6.12459428796224    42.8724842614997\\
7.15525195266944    41.1084954116539\\
8.35935052984777    39.2503059612158\\
9.76607696599646    37.2902568750356\\
11.4095298390967    35.2249825302553\\
13.3295458967289    33.0559683190839\\
15.5726656855012    30.7892160869787\\
18.1932616783216    28.4341294870657\\
21.2548562449431    26.001985060567\\
24.8316614129453    23.5044106916131\\
29.0103777424446    20.9521682657338\\
33.8922959186524    18.3543474238768\\
39.5957520041829    15.7179274647259\\
46.2589958656035    13.0475937242568\\
54.0435423039286    10.3456894891334\\
63.1380861193367    7.61221475935568\\
73.7630760099714    4.84482624825966\\
86.1760581745992    2.03883861986987\\
100.677919146268    -0.812727424497676\\
117.62017918116 -3.71896152579061\\
137.41351299195 -6.69062556953879\\
160.537704365387    -9.73934743987266\\
187.553275960699    -12.8764036780143\\
219.11507619125 -16.1111979370897\\
255.988152530899    -19.4497320625563\\
299.066296008708    -22.8934914466229\\
349.393706404331    -26.4391104664317\\
408.190303301183    -30.0789300868327\\
476.881296528833    -33.8022390929172\\
557.131732772255    -37.5967891245534\\
650.886855746185    -41.4501808203098\\
760.419258251686    -45.3508761893058\\
888.383969065015    -49.2887780321801\\
1037.88280994652    -53.2554439894443\\
1212.53958276194    -57.2440517919334\\
1416.58790922672    -61.2492268819669\\
1654.97385247943    -65.2668147050258\\
1933.47580799679    -69.2936486651507\\
2258.84456996598    -73.3273402158315\\
2638.96696827626    -77.3661015092111\\
3083.05704263578    -81.4086019010856\\
3601.87938781013    -85.453855160771\\
4208.01008379661    -89.5011325681274\\
4916.14153579409    -93.5498968898772\\
5743.43861318751    -97.5997527179224\\
6709.9547202367 -101.650409382183\\
7839.11788388376    -105.701653397379\\
9158.29864128477    -109.753328069761\\
10699.4734924696    -113.805318444481\\
12500   -117.857540217111\\
125000  -177.855818006582\\
12500000    -297.855800608783\\
12500000000 -477.855800607043\\
125000000000000 -717.855800607043\\
1e+20   -1072.04119982656\\
};
\addlegendentry{G}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.396in,
height=1.519in,
at={(0.883in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every x tick/.append style={white!40!black},
xmode=log,
xmin=0.1,
xmax=10000,
xminorticks=true,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
every y tick/.append style={white!40!black},
ymin=-271.8,
ymax=-88.2,
ytick={-270, -180,  -90},
ylabel={Phase (deg)},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, forget plot]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-20   -90\\
2e-16   -90\\
2e-11   -90.0000000001192\\
2e-07   -90.0000011917522\\
0.0002  -90.0011917522137\\
0.02    -90.1191750685891\\
0.2 -91.1915994520071\\
0.233656357180521   -91.3920588370423\\
0.272976466254357   -91.6262132012483\\
0.318913433505023   -91.8997098208252\\
0.372580755643581   -92.2191326751401\\
0.435279310596225   -92.5921520073445\\
0.508528890349814   -93.0276942962854\\
0.594105040200952   -93.5361332938739\\
0.694082097379708   -94.1295012943638\\
0.810883472289793   -94.821717178047\\
0.947340391165627   -95.6288233669343\\
1.10676052404865    -96.5692167028282\\
1.29300816160207    -97.6638470972376\\
1.51059788422311    -98.9363409134281\\
1.76480399396087    -100.412981525118\\
2.06178836183266    -102.122445888259\\
2.40874978951507    -104.095153797879\\
2.8140985058872 -106.362041505682\\
3.28766002816376    -108.95253986257\\
3.84091332914377    -111.891553048939\\
4.48726908366921    -115.19535305449\\
5.24239473889462    -118.866594755154\\
6.12459428796224    -122.889151843887\\
7.15525195266944    -127.224090420932\\
8.35935052984777    -131.808541392855\\
9.76607696599646    -136.559043192485\\
11.4095298390967    -141.379779630612\\
13.3295458967289    -146.174305744534\\
15.5726656855012    -150.857805109704\\
18.1932616783216    -155.366677558834\\
21.2548562449431    -159.663487934238\\
24.8316614129453    -163.737170490962\\
29.0103777424446    -167.599795472136\\
33.8922959186524    -171.281657391288\\
39.5957520041829    -174.826123049704\\
46.2589958656035    -178.285044418623\\
54.0435423039286    -181.714955581377\\
63.1380861193367    -185.173876950296\\
73.7630760099714    -188.718342608712\\
86.1760581745992    -192.400204527864\\
100.677919146268    -196.262829509038\\
117.62017918116 -200.336512065762\\
137.41351299195 -204.633322441166\\
160.537704365387    -209.142194890296\\
187.553275960699    -213.825694255466\\
219.11507619125 -218.620220369388\\
255.988152530899    -223.440956807515\\
299.066296008708    -228.191458607145\\
349.393706404331    -232.775909579068\\
408.190303301183    -237.110848156113\\
476.881296528833    -241.133405244846\\
557.131732772255    -244.80464694551\\
650.886855746185    -248.108446951061\\
760.419258251686    -251.04746013743\\
888.383969065015    -253.637958494318\\
1037.88280994652    -255.904846202121\\
1212.53958276194    -257.877554111741\\
1416.58790922672    -259.587018474882\\
1654.97385247943    -261.063659086572\\
1933.47580799679    -262.336152902762\\
2258.84456996598    -263.430783297172\\
2638.96696827626    -264.371176633066\\
3083.05704263578    -265.178282821953\\
3601.87938781013    -265.870498705636\\
4208.01008379661    -266.463866706126\\
4916.14153579409    -266.972305703715\\
5743.43861318751    -267.407847992655\\
6709.9547202367 -267.78086732486\\
7839.11788388376    -268.100290179175\\
9158.29864128477    -268.373786798752\\
10699.4734924696    -268.607941162958\\
12500   -268.808400547993\\
125000  -269.880824931411\\
12500000    -269.998808247786\\
12500000000 -269.999998808248\\
125000000000000 -269.999999999881\\
1e+20   -270\\
};
\addlegendentry{G}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xtick={\empty},
xlabel={Frequency  (rad/s)},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ytick={\empty},
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Bode Diagram},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}% 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do a `\addlegendentry{G}` and the only plot you have states `forget plot`. So there is no plot available to add the legend entry... (yep, the error message is not so helpful).

So the solution is to eliminate the `forget plot`:

```
[...]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,
%forget plot
]
[...]
```

(in both places)

[image]

Comment: @joe --- the wrong code was generated by `matlab2tikz` or it was due to a manual edit? Because in the first case it would be nice to make a bug report.

Comment: the wrong code was automatically generated by matlab2tikz.  Thanks!

Comment: @nico-schlömer --- this seems a bug in matlab2tikz. Just an head-up... ;-)